# If an astronaut threw a cup of coffee into space, would it freeze, or boil off into gas?

Tags: physics, water, temperature, vacuum

If an astronaut threw a cup of coffee into space somehow, would it freeze into a block, or boil off into gas due to the zero pressure?

Comment: depends where you throw it imo. If it is directly facing the sun, it might boil and If it is thrown elsewhere it will freeze.

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/what-would-happen-if-we-released-water-into-deep-space?r=SearchResults

Comment: This answer contains videos showing water dumps from the shuttle. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33876/6944

Comment: Both? Evaporation is a cooling process. Some of the liquid would quickly evaporate, lowering the temperature to the point where the rest of it froze. Then [the frozen particles themselves would evaporate.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(phase_transition))

Comment: It's not even necessary to go to space to run the experiment.  If it gets cold enough here on earth, you can throw a pan of boiling water into the air and it will disappear before it hits the ground.

Comment: Is this not basically how [instant coffee is produced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_coffee#Freeze_drying)?

Comment: Ice can evaporate. I've washed my car in below freezing weather, and didn't bother drying it one time. All the frozen droplets evaporated overnight while in a sub-zero garage. It was very clearly sub-zero, around -20C, and there's no way it remotely went above zero the whole time the car was in the garage. No sun, no temperature rise, just evaporation of small droplets of ice.

Comment: @MadHatter that reminds me I need to add a photo here. I'll get some started today... [What component(s) of instant coffee make it deliquescent?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/104490)

Comment: The coffee would disperse away from you in a cloud of frozen snow. The other astronauts, OTOH, would converge on you in a boiling mob because you threw away their coffee.

Comment: [Another possible relevent SE site](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) :)

Comment: How is the coffee held in the cup in the first place?

Comment: Why would it "boil" into gas?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This was tested nearly sixty years ago. Using a very large cup filled with 95 tons of water. An empty second stage of a Saturn I under test was used. Only the first stage should be tested but with full payload of a water-filled dummy upper stage. Dummies with the tanks but without the expensive engines. The dummies should have the same shape and mass as a real second stage and the center of mass should be at the same position. The test of the first stage required dummies with water ballast anyway, only an explosive charge was needed to release the water at the highest point.

From [this archived NASA media page](https://web.archive.org/web/20110517155438/http://nix.ksc.nasa.gov/info;jsessionid=2916kf84ibbt0?id=MSFC-6203276&orgid=11):

> [image]
>
> **Date**:     04.25.1962
> **Title**:    Saturn I SA-2 Launch
> **Description**:      The second flight of the Saturn I vehicle, the SA-2, was successfully launched from Cape Canaveral, Florida on April
> 15, 1962. This vehicle had a secondary mission. After the first stage
> shutoff, at a 65-mile altitude, the water-filled upper stage was
> exploded, dumping 95 tons of water in the upper atmosphere. The
> resulting massive ice cloud rose to a height of 90 miles. The
> experiment, called Project Highwater, was intended to investigate the
> effects on the ionosphere of the sudden release of such a great volume
> of water.
> **ID**:   MSFC-6203276
> **Credit**:   [NASA Marshall Space Flight Center (NASA-MSFC)](https://web.archive.org/web/20110517155438/http://mix.msfc.nasa.gov/)

So the water would not freeze to a block but to a cloud of ice crystals. These small ice particles would not melt but turn into water vapor directly. This is called sublimation: when a solid goes directly to vapor without a liquid state between solid and gaseous.

But how does the water turn into ice? The liquid water releases some vapor and cools down by the vaporisation. So a part of the liquid goes to vapor and the rest to ice. Vaporisation of water removes a lot of heat energy.

A [report](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19790078055/downloads/19790078055.pdf) of 127 pages was written.

But what about the cup of coffee? In zero gravity you can't handle liquids in cups. In the pressurized capsule, the coffee will float free, its shape will be a sphere. If you depressurize the capsule to expose the coffee to the vacuum of space, the water will boil at lower air pressure, a part will turn into vapor and the rest into ice crystals. The ice crystals will be vented together with the air into space. When pressure is so low that the hatch may be opened only very few crystals are left in the capsule.

If you want to see what happens to a small water volume in space, you need a closed and pressurized bottle to take the water out of the capsule. If you open the bottle, you will see the cloud of ice crystals.

[Wikipedia: Project Highwater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Highwater)

Comment: I don't see how a huge tank of water *being exploded* tells us anything about what will happen to cup of coffee hand-tossed into space. Yes, there are physical processes called vaporization, sublimation, and thermal radiation, but what would actually happen in a given situation will depend a lot on initial conditions, and these conditions don't match those discussed in the question.

Comment: @uhoh Assuming it happened in a chamber simulating the cold and vacuum of space.

Comment: @trognanders It's important to understand that space has no temperature. *Things* in space do though, and that temperature depends heavily on whether they are in sunlight and how much of it they absorb. For example, the surface of the moon [gets pretty hot in the sun.](https://www.space.com/18175-moon-temperature.html)

Comment: Why do you think it will be fully vaporized before the pressure reaches zero? The cup of coffee does not have enough energy to vaporize all the coffee, does it? I would expect it to start to boil, the temperature would quickly decrease and if you didn't lower the pressure too quickly, it should stay in one piece due to the surface tension and ultimately become a solid block of stronger coffee.

Comment: Saturn 1 was a 2 stage rocket using an S-I and S-IV stages.  This test had a dummy second stage and a dummy payload fairing in the vague shape of an Apollo capsule and service module.  IN theory Saturn I and V (along with most if not all of the other study variants) could have carried an S-V stage derived from a Centaur on top.  But that configuration was never developed beyond assorted paper studies.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica "space has no temperature." Yes and no. For every point in space, there is a temperature such that a black body at that temperature would be at thermal equilibrium. Thus there is a sense in which that point in space has that temperature.

Comment: This gives me an idea for a coffee cup with a tether tied to the rim, so you can twirl it around while you work to keep the coffee inside it.

Comment: @Acccumulation but also no in the sense that vacuum doesn't allow convective cooling, and radiative cooling at 370K is awfully slow.

Comment: @Accumulation That's not [the scientific](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature) nor even [the colloquial](https://buythermopro.com/knowledge/where-to-put-outdoor-thermometer/) definition of temperature though.

Comment: @Fax What exactly are you claiming is the scientific definition of temperature that would not be applicable to space? I can think of two definitions: first, that if two objects of different temperatures are in thermal contact then heat will flow from the one at higher temperature to the one at lower temperature (zeroth law); second, the mathematical definition $1/T = \partial S/\partial U$. Either of those can be used to determine a temperature for a small region of space about as well as it would apply to a small region of matter.

Comment: @DavidZ Temperature is a measure of a quality of a state of a material. Space being cold is a vacuous truth.

Answer (score 31):

It would not freeze *into a block*. It would quickly expand and boil, but not in a rolling boil. Without pressure, bubbles would form throughout the coffee and expand rapidly, causing it to spray out of the mug as soon as you released the catch that would have been necessary to hold the lid on. But evaporation causes cooling, so millions of frozen coffee crystals would form and quickly disperse. At our distance from the sun the crystals would then evaporate (that is, sublime) over time. In deep space, far from the sun, they might last indefinitely.

Comment: This is *really interesting!* Bubbles usually like to nucleate (streams of bubbles up the sides of a glass of beer/soda, Mentos dropped in a bottle of Coke) so the competition between rapid disassembly via fizzing vs radiative + evaporative cooling/freezing means it depends on how hard the coffee is thrown/if it breaks up into droplets, and the quality of the filter used and the fineness of the grind.

Comment: So, essentially - the coffee would turn into snow.

Comment: @SF. Coffee Snow sounds like a name for a delicious icecream.

Comment: I am assuming there would be enough particulates in the coffee that, with the boiling point now so much lower than the temperature, nucleation would happen in lots of places. But possibly bubbles rapidly forming  against the mug surface would be the main ejector; I'm not sure it would look noticeably different.

Comment: Frozen coffee bubbles sounds more like a frozen cappuccino. What would the Italians and [Australians](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FGUkxn5kZQ) say?

Comment: FWIW without gravity, bubbles created via nucleation wouldn't have anywhere to go in particular. Instead of rising to the top they'd push the liquid around assuming there was an egress for it.

Comment: @aslum with a roughly 1000:1 volume ratio, if say 1% of the water rapidly turned to gas as bubbles uniformly, the water volume would be forced to accelerate radially outwards and expand very quickly to *ten times its original size*; and with nothing (except surface tension) to stop it it's possible it would just blow itself outwards and keep going. We normally think of bubbles in water coming from dissolved gas, nucleating slowly. But I think it would look more like this ("ancient history" from 2009) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwyMcV9emmc

Comment: " Coffee Snow sounds like a name for a delicious icecream. "  Or a 90s rock band.  Didn't Coffee Snow open for Nirvana for a while?  Sublimation is the right answer, IMHO.  In a vacuum the water in the coffee will try to fill the container it was poured into, and space is big.  Solar and cosmic radiation will then likely break the molecules down into atoms.

Comment: I wonder if it is similar to the throwing a boiling mug of water into the air when it is extremely cold outside experiment?

Comment: @trognanders Yes, I think so. The difference is that it would expand more rapidly in space because of the lack of air, so it would dissipate into invisibility quite quickly. The same analogy is made in an answer to this related question (also linked to above): https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/24639/what-would-happen-if-we-released-water-into-deep-space?r=SearchResults

Comment: I think the water would principally continue to sublimate even far from the sun, but very slowly, over cosmological times, or the [comets](https://www.mpe.mpg.de/5295823/News_20140123) would have lost their ice.

Comment: @SF. coffee snow. Which will then rapidly sublimate off the remaining ice, making a very fine instant coffee powder. Which, with my luck, would immediately settle on the nearest camera lens and befoul it.

Comment: @T.Sar Haha! :) Fresh from outer space.

Comment: @uhoh: If you start with hot coffee, the rapid expansion is quite likely. If you start with coffee near freezing temperature, the expansion would be way more moderate, as latent heat of evaporation of water is quite high, so after quickly dropping the water temperature to zero through the initial boil-off it would take quite a while for the remainder to acquire enough heat to create more bubbles. If you start off with ice latte, you're likely to see only slightly frothy lump of ice.

Answer (score 1):

While the existing answers appear mostly right to me, especially on the "part will turn into vapor and the rest into ice crystals" fact, I think they omit one interesting explanation. Namely, *why* does evaporation cause cooling - understanding which seems to suggest the exact effect will depend on *how violently* you throw the cup.

While I've never conducted such an experiment in 0g, I have done it repeatedly in 1g, to explain this particular phenomenon. So, I'll start with the part I have seen (using water and a vacuum pump).

What is evaporation? Is it random which part of a liquid evaporates and which remains? Not quite. On the microscopic level it is, somewhat self-explanatory, the molecules which break past the surface that form the vapour. Now, in the liquid, as elsewhere, the molecules have a distribution of different kinetic energy values. The ones most likely to escape are those with the highest kinetic energy. When these are gone, the ones which stayed have, on average, lower kinetic energy. This energy is precisely the temperature - getting lower.

So, you'll have the higher-energy molecules turn to vapour, and the low ones - into ice. In 1g, those stay together at the bottom of the vessel. For a bit of 0-g speculation: depending on how big the cup is, and how violently it is thrown, I'd think these low-energy remnants can form larger or smaller ice crystals. Most will be vapour either way.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming total darkness and a coffee temperature below the boiling point in space The coffee can only cool down by emitting radiation. If the coffee is thrown out hot or cold has the only difference that it takes a bit longer for the hot coffee to freeze than the cold coffee. If the space is dark and the coffee is given a lot of velocities it will get torn into small droplets and it will cool down and freeze. If the droplets are very small, almost immediately all heat will be radiated away. So if you can throw like spraying it will be a nice sight.
The radiation loss of the coffee will be the highest for large sheets of connected coffee. A flat sheet of coffee will radiate its heat away the fastest. So if you manage to throw a sheet of coffee out of the cup, you will see the sheet turning solid. The thinner the sheet the faster it freezes.
The frozen coffee will end up in thermodynamic equilibrium with the vacuum of space, reaching a shivering temperature of about 2.7(K).

The temperature of the water is below the boiling temperature on Earth. But in space this boiling temperature is lower. So if it has the boiling temperature of space it will be boiled to small droplets, causing a spray. No matter how you throw it. For lower temperatures, the above scenario suffices.

Comment: "coffee temperature below the boiling point in space" Not going to happen.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Why not?

Comment: What is the boiling point of water in a vacuum?

Comment: @OrganicMarble On yop of the Mount Everest it's about 69 degrees celsius. I guess in space it's about 50 degrees?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point

Comment: @OrganicMarble But in space the pressure is zero. Why shouldn't water boil in space? If I heat it up then at a point bubbles will appear. They will not rise to a surface though. They will grow and tear the water up.

Comment: @Methadont: I don't think the problem is that the water _won't_ boil, I think the problem is that the water will _always_ boil in a vacuum. Even _steel_ sublimates in a vacuum (slowly)

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't think so. If the water is near 0 degrees (but above it) it will stay liquid.

Comment: @Methadont: All liquids and solids subliminate at 0 pressure, regardless of temperature. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132341/do-all-liquids-boil-in-a-vacuum

Comment: @MooingDuck Bt why can't water boil and sublimate at the same time?

Comment: @Methadont Water can't be liquid at pressures below the triple point, and as such it doesn't literally boil. As Mooing Duck correctly points out, it does sublimate, which is basically the same thing but without being a liquid. It's what dry ice does.

Comment: @Fax So in a liquid body of water in space, no bubbles will appear if you increase its temperature?

Comment: @Methadont  water can boil and sublimate at the same time only when the temperature is at the triple point of water where all three forms may exist together, solid ice, liquid water and gaseous vapor. But for sublimation there must be a surface between solid and gaseous water without a thin layer of water between both.